# Monitor thread synchronization in python

Tags: python, synchronization

Is there any way to use monitor thread synchronization like java methods synchronization,in python class to ensure thread safety and avoid race condition?

I want a monitor like synchronization mechanism that allows only one method call in my class or object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [python threading interface](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html). For simple mutual exclusion functionality you might use a `Lock` object. You can easily do this using the `with` statement like:

```
...
lock = Lock()
...
with (lock):
  # This code will only be executed by one single thread at a time
  # the lock is released when the thread exits the 'with' block
  ...
```

See also [here](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) for an overview of different thread synchronization mechanisms in python.

There is no python language construct for Java's `synchronized` (but I guess it could be built using decorators)

Comment: Would you update the web link?

Answer (score 2):

I built a simple prototype for it, here's a link to the GitHub repository for all the details : https://github.com/m-a-rahal/monitor-sync-python

I used inheritance instead of decorators, but maybe I'll include that option later
Here's what the 'Monitor' super class looks like:

```py
import threading

class Monitor(object):
   def __init__(self, lock = threading.Lock()):
       ''' initializes the _lock, threading.Lock() is used by default '''
       self._lock = lock


   def Condition(self):
       ''' returns a condition bound to this monitor's lock'''
       return threading.Condition(self._lock)

   init_lock = __init__
```

Now all you need to do **to define your own monitor** is to inherit from this class:

```py
class My_Monitor_Class(Monitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_lock() # just don't forget this line, creates the monitor's _lock
        cond1 = self.Condition()
        cond2 = self.Condition()
        # you can see i defined some 'Condition' objects as well, very simple syntax
        # these conditions are bound to the lock of the monitor
```

you can also pass your own lock instead

```py
class My_Monitor_Class(Monitor):
    def __init__(self, lock):
        self.init_lock(lock)
```

check out [threading.Condition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) documentation

Also you need to protect all the 'public' methods with the monitor's lock, like this:

```py
class My_Monitor_Class(Monitor):
    def method(self):
        with self._lock:
            # your code here
```

if you want to use 'private' methods (called inside the monitor), you can either **NOT** protect them with the `_lock` (or else the threads will get stuck), or use [RLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567958/when-and-how-to-use-pythons-rlock) instead for the monitor

## EXTRA TIP

sometimes a monitor consists of 'entrance' and 'exit' protocols

```py
monitor.enter_protocol()
<critical section>
monitor.exit_protocol()
```

in this case, you can exploit python's cool `with` statement :3
just define the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods like this:

```py
class monitor(Monitor):
    def __enter__(self):
        with self._lock:
            # enter_protocol code here
    
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        with self._lock:
            # exit_protocol code here
```

now all you need to do is call the monitor using [with statement](https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/):

```py
with monitor: 
    <critical section>
```